# How to check if a relation exists? M2M

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    group = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group, related_name="users_group",
    )

class Group(models.Model):
    ....
```

How to check in serializer is the `Group` empty (there is no relationship with `User`)

My version is :

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    empty = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        ...
        
    def get_empty(self, obj):
        return not User.objects.filter(group=obj).exists()
```

But maybe there is an even better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a [**`ManyToManyModel`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield), Django automatically defines one in reverse with the value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) as name, so you can use:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    empty = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        # …
        
    def get_empty(self, obj):
        return not group.users_group.exists()
```

But this is not very efficient if you want to serialize a large number of `Group`s: for each `Group` it will make an extra query. You can use a `BooleanField`:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    empty = serializers.BooleanField()
    
    class Meta:
        # …
```

and then in the `APIView` or the `ViewSet` use as `QuerySet` a `QuerySet` where you make an annotation with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) to check if there exists a user for that `Group`:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.annotate(
        empty=~Exists(
            User.objects.filter(group=OuterRef('pk'))
        )
    )
    # …
```